# Attribute Error Person and customer classes

Tags: python

> Write a class named Person with data attributes for a person's name, address, telephone and email. Next, write a class named Customer that is a subclass of the Person class. The Customer class should have a data attribute for a customer number and a Boolean data attribute indicating whether the customer wishes to be one the mailing list. Demonstrate an instance of the Customer class in a simple program.

I am getting an attibute error.

```
, line 6, in main
    '555-987-1549','adsf@asd.com','Y','1153')
TypeError: __init__() takes 5 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

I don't completely follow the point of using the boolean expression so maybe someone could explain why it is being used and help me with why I am getting that error.

Heres my code

class `Person`:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, address, telephone, email):
        self.__name = name
        self.__address = address
        self.__telephone = telephone
        self.__email = email

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_address(self, address):
        self.__address = address

    def set_telephone(self, telephone):
        self.__telephone = telephone

    def set_email(self, email):
        self.__email = email

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_address(self):
        return self.__address

    def get_telephone(self):
        return self.__telephone

    def get_email(self):
        return self.__email
```

Class `Customer`:

```
import Person

class Customer(Person.Person):
    def __init__(self, name, address, telephone, email):
        Person.Person.__init__(self, mail, number)
        self.mailing = 'Y'== True
        self.__mail = mail
        self.__number = number

    def set_mail(self, mail):
        self.__mail = mail

    def set_number(self, number):
        self.__number = number

    def get_mail(self):
        return self.__mail

    def get_number(self):
        return self.__number

    def mailList(self, mail):
        if mailing == True:
            return"On the mailing list"
        else:
            return"Not on the mailing list"

    def __str__(self):
        return "\nName: {}\nAddress: {}\ntelephone: {}\nEmail: {}\nMail: {}\nNumber: {}".\
            format(self.get_name(), self.get_address(),\
                   self.get_telephone(), self.get_email()\
                   , self.mailList(self.get_mail()),self.get_number())
```

`customerTest`:

```
import Customer

def main():

    customer = Customer.Customer('Josh', 'Long st, Dallas TX',\
                                 '555-987-1549','adsf@asd.com','Y','1153')
    print(customer)

main()
```

Comment: You invoke `Customer` with 6 parameters, which then invokes `Person` with two parameters (both are not defined, by the way), but both those constructors require 4 parameters, next to `self`. Also, `self.mailing = 'Y'== True` does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__init__` constructor in `Customer is not correct, numbers of arguments is incorrect.

In `self.mailing` you probably want `True` or `False` based on argument.

```
def __init__(self, name, address, telephone, mail, mailing, number):
        Person.Person.__init__(self, name, address, telephone, mail)
        self.mailing = True if mailing == 'Y' else False
        self.__mail = mail
        self.__number = number
```

Also `mailList` need to use self to refer to current object.

```
def mailList(self, mail):
        if self.mailing == True:
            return"On the mailing list"
        else:
            return"Not on the mailing list"
```

Comment: Thanks I almost got it to work. But the mailing always returns Not on the mailing List do you know what it could be I used the code you gave me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like instead of

```
def __init__(self, name, address, telephone, email):
```

You actually meant:

```
def __init__(self, name, address, telephone, email, mail, number):
```

---

By the way, what is going on here?

```
    self.mailing = 'Y'== True
```

You probably mean

```
    self.mailing = mail == True
```

---

Edit: Yeah, what Tobias said. Please fix this as well including missing parameters -

```
    Person.Person.__init__(self, mail, number)
```

Also while it is not necessary, [you might want to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods) use `super().(...)` syntax instead of calling `Person.__init__(self, ...)` directly.

Comment: ... and also needs to fix the call to super constructor and the `mailList` method...

Answer (score 0):

For Person Class and if you are using Python2.7, define it as inheriting from `Object` class to be able to use [`super`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods) expression properly later when you inherent from this class otherwise if you deal with Python3+, you can just say `super().__init__()`, so:

Person Class will be:

```
class Person(object):#only change
    def __init__(self, name, address, telephone, email):
        self.__name = name
        self.__address = address
        self.__telephone = telephone
        self.__email = email

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_address(self, address):
        self.__address = address

    def set_telephone(self, telephone):
        self.__telephone = telephone

    def set_email(self, email):
        self.__email = email

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_address(self):
        return self.__address

    def get_telephone(self):
        return self.__telephone

    def get_email(self):
        return self.__email
```

As for Customer Class, read code comments where I've made changes

```
import Person

class Customer(Person.Person):
    def __init__(self, name, address, telephone, email, mail, number): #fixed number of arguments to pass for class instantiation 
        super(type(self), self).__init__(name, address, telephone, email) #Also here and not the use of `super`
        #super().__init__(name, address, telephone, email) with Python 3+
        self.mailing = True if mail == 'Y' else False #Fixed self.mailing expression
        self.__mail = mail
        self.__number = number

    def set_mail(self, mail):
       self.__mail = mail

    def set_number(self, number):
        self.__number = number

    def get_mail(self):
        return self.__mail

    def get_number(self):
        return self.__number

    def mailList(self): #No need for mail argument
        if self.mailing == True: #Just Check here self.mailing
            return "On the mailing list"
        else:
            return "Not on the mailing list"

    def __str__(self):
        return "\nName: {}\nAddress: {}\ntelephone: {}\nEmail: {}\nMail: {}\nNumber: {}".\
                format(self.get_name(), self.get_address(),\
                       self.get_telephone(), self.get_email()\
                       , self.mailList(),self.get_number())
```